# mailer symfony 5 + sengrid go to spam

Tags: symfony, mailer

I send information mails from my web app to my clients with Mailer Symfony 5 and Sendgrid, but all my mails go to spam with this message :

```
Content analysis details:   (7.0 points, 5.0 required)
pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                            [score: 0.0000]
3.0 BAD_RECV               No description available.
0.2 HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level
                            mail domains are different
0.1 REPS                   REP: S 0 -> 0 - 69 -> 0.245
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
2.1 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_12     BODY: HTML: images with 800-1200 bytes of
                            words
0.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
                            valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_EF          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                            envelope-from domain
-0.5 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
3.0 KAM_SENDGRID           Sendgrid being exploited by scammers
0.4 HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG  HTML-only message, but there is no HTML
                            tag
0.5 KAM_NUMSUBJECT         Subject ends in numbers excluding current years
-0.0 DKIMWL_WL_MED          DKIMwl.org - Medium trust sender

The original message was not completely plain text, and may be unsafe to
open with some email clients; in particular, it may contain a virus,
or confirm that your address can receive spam.  If you wish to view
it, it may be safer to save it to a file and open it with an editor.
```

I try some mailer options without results.  What can I do to get 5.0 mail note and avoid mails to go to spam box, please ?
Here is the mail code :

```
$email = new Email();
            $email->from(new Address("xxx@yyy.fr", 'yyy'))
                ->html($donnees["message"])
                ->subject($donnees["sujet"]);

            foreach ($donnees["emails"] as $emailForm) {
                $email->addTo(new Address($emailForm));
            }

            if ($donnees["autresEmails"]) {
                $replaced = str_replace(' ', '', $donnees["autresEmails"]);
                $adressesSupp = explode(",", $replaced);
                foreach ($adressesSupp as $adresseSupp) {
                    $email->addTo(new Address($adresseSupp));
                }
            }

            if ($demande->getPdfConfirmationLivraison()) {
                $email->attachFromPath('./uploads/pdfConfirmationLivraison/' . $demande->getPdfConfirmationLivraison());
            }

            try {
                $this->mailer->send($email);
                $this->addFlash('success', 'La confirmation de livraison a bien été envoyée');
            } catch (IOExceptionInterface $exception) {
                $this->addFlash('danger', 'Une erreur est survenue lors de l\'envoi du mail');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem if from your Sendgrid configuration because sendgrid is the sender.

You have to configure SPF and DKIM in order to avoid your mails going to the spam folder.

You can take look at this [source](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/mailer/sender-authentication) for a detailed guide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try to configure authentication domain in sendgrid. If I use SMTP without using sendgrid, do I have to configure SPF and DKIM on the DNS ?